# C++ Getting maximum value from CSVwith year and month from user input without STL

Tags: c++, csv, datetime, io, stl

I'm trying to read from a **CSV** file with the following values.
**dateTime**,DP,Dta,Dts,EV,QFE,QFF,QNH,R,RH,**Speed**,**radiation**,ST,ST2,ST3,ST4,Sx,T

**31/03/2016** 9:00 14.6    175 17  0   1013.4  1016.9  1017    0   68.2    **6 512**   22.7    24.1    25.5    26.1    8   20.74
**31/03/2016 9:10** 14.6    194 22  0.1 1013.4  1016.9  1017    0   67.2    **5 565**   22.7    24.1    25.5    26.1    8   20.97

Currently the column that i need the data from is from dateTime , speed and radiation.
However , when i call on the windlog.print , dateTime is printed every alternate line starting from second line and radiation is printed every alternate line starting from the third line , so i am wondering did i do anything wrong with the ignore function ? 
Cus i am not too farmiliar with it....

Key problem here is we are not suppose to use any STL data structures.
I have written a simple vector class for this.

```
typedef struct
{
 Date d;
 Time t;
 float speed;
 int solar;
}
W;
//Methods

void getMaxSpeed(int y2, int m2);
//var
int choice, year,m, tt;
ifstream input;
string filename,month,num;
Vector<W> windlog;
W T1;
ostream & operator << (ostream & osObject, const WindLogType & W1);
istream & operator >> (istream & input, WindLogType & W1);
int main()
{
 filename = "test.csv";
 string line2,line,sDay, sMonth, sYear, sHH, sMM;

 input.open(filename.c_str());
 input.ignore(500,'\n');
 if(!input.is_open())
 {
    cout<< "File not found."<<endl;
    return 0;
 }
 else
 {
    while(getline(input,line))
    {
        //Get Date
        getline(input, sDay,'/');
        getline(input, sMonth,'/');
        getline(input, sYear,' ');
        //Get Time
        getline(input, sHH,':');
        getline(input, sMM,',');
        //Parse into variable , convert from string to int
        int day1 = atoi(sDay.c_str());
        int month1 = atoi(sMonth.c_str());
        int year1 = atoi(sYear.c_str());
        int hour1 = atoi(sHH.c_str());
        int min1 = atoi(sMM.c_str());

        float s1; 
        int sr;
        // speed
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            input >> s1;
            input.ignore(100, ',');
        }
        //radiation
        for(int j =0; j<18; j++)
        {
            input >> sr;
            input.ignore(90,',');
        }

        // create a record
        T1.d.setDate(day1, month1, year1);
        T1.t.setTime(hour1, min1);
        T1.speed = s1;
        T1.solar = sr;

        windlog.push_back(T1);         
    }
}
windlog.print();
getMaxSpeed(2017,3);

return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get the maximum speed based on the year and month from user input accordingly.
But the current output for getMaxSpeed(2017,3) is:
'Maximum Wind Speed for the year 2017 in the 3rd month is : 6.30584e-044'
So i need to know what is the proper syntax to filter accordingly .
**GetMaximumValue method**

```
void getMaxSpeed(int y2, int m2)
{

 float maxSpeed;
 for (int i=0; i<windlog.size(); i++)
 {
    int y3 = windlog.at(i).d.getYear();
    int m3 = windlog.at(i).d.getMonth();
    if(y3==y2 && m3==m2){
    while(y3==y2 && m3==m2)
    {
        maxSpeed = windlog.at(0).speed;
        if (windlog.at(i).speed > maxSpeed)
        {
            maxSpeed = windlog.at(i).speed;
        }
     }

    }
  }
  cout<< maxSpeed << endl;

  }
```

Once i figure out for the maxspeed i will be able to do the rest of the functions....

Comment: FYI: `std::string`, `std::ifstream`, `atoi`, and `std::getline` are all part of the standard library.

Comment: "...we are not suppose to use any STL libraries.." why are you using C++ then?

Comment: sorry i meant data structures

Comment: The data structure you provided doesn't parse with commas, it would parse with spaces.

Comment: @AnniePng I'll also ask, why are you using C++ then? What is the logic of using one part of the language but not the other? Besides - strings and streams are also data sructures.

Comment: Is this schoolwork or an interview question? That would be the **only** case where one could ask you to avoid containers like `std::vector`

Comment: On the `getMaxSpeed` function, shouldn't your `maxSpeed=windlog.at.(0).speed` be outside of the for loop? Also, your while should trigger an infinite loop.

Comment: its school work. for ds stl like we cant use the max function from vector libraries.@Riet , but dont i need to get the max value with the while condition ? and it's from csv so its seperated by comma , no?

Comment: There's information online about how the stl containers work internally. You could look that up, and implement something like that.

Comment: @AnniePng You're already iterating over every element of `windlog` in the outer `for` loop. Your outer `if` filters to only elements of `windlog` that you want. The inner `if` will ensure that you find the maximum speed. The `while` compares (the same) single element repeatedly

Comment: @AnniePng CSV can be a generic term for any single character delimited file type. Look at your data. From what you've posted, the headers are comma delimited, and the data is space delimited.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've provided, you're telling `ignore` to look for a comma, but there aren't any in your data, so it eats 90 or 100 characters instead. If you change the delimiter to ' ', you should get the results you want

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius  If you read the post, the OP specifically asks if they're misusing the ignore function. This answer specifically assesses the question the OP raises. The OP title is misleading.

Comment: Of course, if you edit your answer, things change. :p